# Firebase Cloud Firestore read data removed from Firebase Console long time ago

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I do a foreach in order to read all the documents in a collection it returns documents that I removed from firebase console long time ago.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If data was really removed, it would never show up in a query again.  Please edit your question to include all the relevant code, including what you're doing to remove documents, and the query that apparently gets the deleted documents.

Comment: Ok thank you Doug, I removed documents direcly from the firebase console not within the code, nevertheless I´m going to put the code,

Comment: Finally I removed the data with code, and it works, but directly in the firebase console it didn´t work. To remove it I use https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data?hl=es-419